# What does 「ひざっこぞうをたたいてみるよ」 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, phrases, song-lyrics

This is a line from the song 「結婚しようよ」by 吉田{よしだ}拓郎{たくろう} ([youtube link](https://youtu.be/ryutpbPwrz4?t=136))

Relevant piece of lyrics:

> 雨が上がって雲のきれ間に
>
> お陽様さんが見えたら
>
> **ひざっこぞうをたたいてみるよ**
>
> 結婚しようよMMMM

[Source](http://www.utamap.com/showkasi.php?surl=36495)

When I googled it, I came across 膝を叩く which seems to be used when you "get" something (an element of surprise where you tap your knees to show it) but I don't think it has that meaning here.

Also, I could not find a proper meaning for ひざっこぞう but I could find a meaning for ひざこぞう (kneecap) which means the っ is probably used for emphasis.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your interpretation of 「ひざっこぞう」 is correct.

ひざっこぞう ＝ ひざこぞう ＝ ひざ ＝ most technically, ひざ頭{がしら}

By adding the こぞう（小僧）= "a little boy", it personifies the word 「ひざ」 = "kneecap".

Regarding the meaning of 「ひざっこぞうをたたいてみるよ」,  I have always thought (in Japanese, of course, as I did not speak a word of English when this song came out) that it meant something along the lines of "***I'll slap my thigh (and cavort around.)***".

In other words, it means to me "I'll be saying 'This is it!  I've gotta marry her (or propose to her)!'"

Comment: Why community wiki?

Comment: いあ、解答ゆうよりも個人的見解に近いと思うたさかいに・・

Comment: Does personifying the knee signify something? Is this the reason why there's `and cavort around.` nuance to the sentence as well? 

Overall I understood what you are saying (that personal anecdote helped). Thank you so much!